# Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll

Tags: python-3.x, python.net

I am trying to call a c# function from python. The code I am using is as follows:

```
def solve_it(input_data):
    assignment1Object = Assignment1()
    return assignment1Object.Assignment1Solution()

from pythonnet import load
load('netfx')
import clr
clr.AddReference('path/to/dll/DiscreteOptimizationSolutions.dll')
from DiscreteOptimizationSolutions import Assignment1
result = solve_it()
print('This script submits the integer: %s\n' % solve_it(''))
```

But it throws error saying :

```
RuntimeError: Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll
Failed to initialize pythonnet: 
System.InvalidOperationException: This property must be set before runtime is initialized
at Python.Runtime.Runtime.set_PythonDLL(String value)
at Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
at Python.Runtime.Runtime.set_PythonDLL(String value)
at Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
```

I am using python version 3.10.9 on Anaconda with pythonnet 3.0.1

Comment: If you are importing in the same kernel `import clr` more than once you will get this error. This is python.net bug in ipython when using the default .NET Framework. Starting with fresh python kernel probably will help you but will make debugging harder. Or `load("coreclr")` before `import crl`.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/2099 if it is similar to your experience.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs if we copy the virtual environment files from one system to other. To resolve this, go to the virtual environment directory > lib > site-packages and open properties of Python.Runtime.dll file.

In General tab, there will be "Unblock" checkbox.
Check this checkbox & hit OK to close the properties popup.
Run the python code again to see its working!

[image: File path]